# Converting a string in the form of a list to a list of integers

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I have a list containing numbers the type of which is string. How can I convert the input to a list of integers?

input:

```
'[1, 3, 6, 8]'
```

desired output:

```
[1, 3, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `eval()` here, and directly evaluate your string input:

```
inp = '[1, 3, 6, 8]'
output = eval(inp)
print(output)  # [1, 3, 6, 8]
```

Another approach, using `re.findall`:

```
output = [int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+', x)]
print(output)  # [1, 3, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import ast


my_list = ast.literal_eval('[1, 3, 6, 8]')
```

Another option is the builtin function `eval()` but `ast.literal_eval()` is safer. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval).

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex

```
ip ='[1, 3, 6, 8]'

import re
opt = [int(a) for a in re.findall("\d+",ip)]
print(opt)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use from the [JSON standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) the method [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json

string = '[1, 3, 6, 8]'
res = json.loads(string)
print(res)
#=> [1, 3, 6, 8]
```

And got the required list of integers:

```
all([ isinstance(e, int) for e in res ])
#=> True
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex `re.findall` this can be achieved as below:

```
import re
test_string = '[1, 3, 6, 8]'
res = re.findall(r'\d+', test_string)
# Map every entry to int
res = list(map(int, res))
  
print (res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a safe way of doing so without importing any libraries:

```
s = '[1, 3, 6, 8]'
print(list(map(int, ''.join(i if i.isdigit() else ' ' for i in s).split())))
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 6, 8]
```

---

Explanation:

Lets have a look at the line:

```
list(map(int, ''.join(i if i.isdigit() else ' ' for i in s).split()))
```

On the outside we are merely mapping a list of strings to integers, so lets get rid of that part first:

```
''.join(i if i.isdigit() else ' ' for i in s).split()
```

Now we can see that we are replacing every character in the `s` string that is not a digit with a whitespace, and then we are splitting the string by whitespaces, resulting in

```
['1', '3', '6', '8']
```

which can then be mapped to a list of integers.